# Wifi with two computers with ubuntu not working

Tags: wireless, networking

At my home network everytime I try to connect to the internet my two computers with Ubuntu 12.04 at the same time to the router via WiFi the connection fails. Only one gets connection to the internet. It happends with any other computer with ubuntu (the bug is hardware independent). If i switch to windows in any machine the porblem dissapears

I need help. I need my internet in my two computers at home.

NEW INFO (08/jan/2014):

Ok, I have discovered 2 things
1. The problem also is with my android smartphone.
2. The problem seems to be the router's firmware or settings. The same router from another ISP gave no issues, even with more linux devices in the network.

A partial solution is to assign fixed ip addresses to all linux devices. It works most of the time. I need confirmation please.

Comment: Same problem here. Two machines with ubuntu 13.04. They have different IP's each can connect to the wifi as soon as the other machine is disconnected. When both are connected, only one can access Internet, the other not. Although the machine that cannot access Internet has a connection to the router, it can't access the router either.

Answer (score 0):

Does the router give you automatically a IP-address or do you use a fixed one?

Please post the (terminal) output of:

> ifconfig -a

from both computers.